# UTC time zones calculation

Tags: xquery, osb

Departuredatetime:2015-08-15T09:50:00 (GMToffset=10)

Arrivaldatetime:2015-08-15T06:30:00(GMToffset=-7)

FlightDuration= Arrivaldatetime-Departuredatetime
so Flithtduration =13:40 hours, it is giving,

but how it is calculating i am unable to understand, according to which formula it is giving 13:40 hours,could you pls help and explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

2015-08-15T09:50:00 (GMToffset=10) = 2015-08-14T23:50:00Z

2015-08-15T06:30:00(GMToffset=-7) = 2015-08-15T13:30:00Z

**= 13h40m**

I think you need to brush up on your time zone concepts a bit, because there's nothing wrong with the calculation itself. If you're feeding it bad data it will return bad results.